# Obtenga el valor de javascript e inclúyalo en el valor del campo hidden del formulario

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente código Javascript:

```
 <script>
      function getLocation(){
          var lat;
          var lon;
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{   
            lat = document.getElementById("lat").value=pos.coords.latitude;
            lon = document.getElementById("lon").value=pos.coords.longitude;
          });
      }
      getLocation();
      </script>
```

Con este código obtengo la latitud y longitud del usuario, pero me gustaría incluirlo en los valores de los campos ocultos del siguiente formulario:

```
<form method="post">          
      <input type="submit" name="BtnLocalizacao" value="Minha Localização" onclick="getLocation()">
  </form>
```

Para recuperar los valores con POST.

```
 <?php if($_POST["BtnLocalizacao"] == "Minha Localização"){ ?>
          
<form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="Latitude" id="lat">
   <input type="hidden" name="Longitude" id="lon">
   <input type="submit" name="BtnSalvar" value="Salvar">
</form>

     <?php } ?>
```

Pero no puedo. ¿Cómo puedo pasar valores de JavaScript, pasar al campo hidden y recuperarlos con la publicación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haz lo siguiente:
pon var lat = document.getElementById("lat")
en una línea, y en la siguiente:
lat.value = latitud

Comment: Hola Gamer. Lo intenté de esa manera, tampoco funciono.

Comment: Te da algún error en específico ?

Comment: Y estuve pensando y me parece que deberías usar fetch() en lugar de poner inputs ocultos para enviar los datos al servidor. Los inputs sí están tomando el valor solo que en la página no se van a ver precisamente porque están ocultos.

Comment: El error que aparece es `Error de tipo no capturado: no se pueden establecer propiedades de nulo (estableciendo 'value')`, que es la línea `lat = document.getElementById("lat").value=pos.coords.latitude;`

Comment: Hice un ajuste a mi código y lo incluí en la publicación, pero aún no está obteniendo el valor.

Comment: Haz lo siguiente: pon var lat = document.getElementById("lat") en una línea y en la siguiente: lat.value = latitud

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Luego cambia tu respuesta para que yo acepte.

Comment: Respuesta editada. 